# Question Regarding How Profile Mate Did Something

Tags: python, selenium

I am wondering how https://profilemate.com/ made instant retrievals of all the followers of an Instagram account. Then, of all those follower accounts, they retrieved the following properties:

Username

Full Name

Follower Count

Following Count

Public Email

Engagement Rate

Website in URL

Total Posts

Business Category

Phone Country

Public Phone Number

City

Link to Account

So far, I can retrieve all the followers using Selenium to scrape the account (on localhost—XAMPP's Apache). Then I can retrieve all the properties of those accounts using a similar method.

But, there are issues running Selenium on GoDaddy, namely the installation process, running python on GoDaddy hosting, etc. Also, we don't want the Selenium popup on GoDaddy since this is a customer-facing web app.

Comment: I imagine they scrape the data from the page as you suggest put use a background process. This can be done in the background without a "popup" as you suggested. You should maybe look into running your driver headless or better yet look into using [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to scrape the page and parse this data.

Comment: Yes, I can do Chrome Options headless (Selenium option) but Selenium doesn't work at all on GoDaddy. Also, BS4 wouldn't work here since it requires a click on Followers to retrieve the popup modal. Also, tried web scraping APIs but none of them have click functionality (they do have RenderJS though). Also, I tried AJAX request on XHR when user clicks Followers tab but that doesn't really work either. I know it's possible since ProfileMate did it but not really sure how they did it. Can anyone point me in some direction? Thanks.

Comment: All described here sounds as though it can be performed through ```BS4``` for sure. I would assume that the modal you speak off is already generated on the page and is a matter of searching through the HTML to find exactly what you are looking.

Comment: Thanks for your idea but the Instagram account page (e.g., instagram.com/[username]) is dynamic and also the followers list isn't retrieved until you click the Followers tab. I checked as well what you said :)